# How to connect http server using Swift and Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Hi I new at swift and I got problem with server connection. I am trying to make request using a method post to login to server using username and password. How I can connect to the server and authentificate?

error messsage:

```
 ["id": <null>, "error": {
    code = "-32700";
    message = "Parse error";
}, "jsonrpc": 2.0]
```

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
   var userName = "root"
   var password = "admin01"

 //   http://192.168.1.1/ubus
   //var LOGIN_TOKEN = 0000000000000000
    let url: String = "http://192.168.1.1/ubus"
    let param: [String: Any] = ["username": "admin", "password": "admin01", "token": "0000000000000000"]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                print("error calling post")
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
            }

            // make sure we got some JSON since that's what we expect
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
                print("didn't get todo object as JSON from API")
                print("Error: \(response.result.error)")
                return
            }

            print(json)
    }


    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Json at server which I need to get:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[0,{"ubus_rpc_session":"07e111d317f7c701dc4dfde1b0d4862d","timeout":300,"expires":300,"acls":{"access-group":{"superuser":["read","write"],"unauthenticated":["read"]},"ubus":{"*":["*"],"session":["access","login"]},"uci":{"*":["read","write"]}},"data":{"username":"root"}}]}
```

**Request should look like:**

```
"{ \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\": 1, \"method\": \"call\", \"params\": [ \"00000000000000000000000000000000\", \"session\", \"login\", { \"username\": \"root\", \"password\": \"admin01\"  } ] }"
```

Comment: Try to change let param: [String: Any] to let param: [String: String]

Comment: Tried this couple time, didn't help

Comment: Have you tried hitting your url in browser?

Comment: Bassicly this url is router and url not working on browser, but using android with request it's work perfectly

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http

Comment: I need to make this loooking request "{ \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\": 1, \"method\": \"call\", \"params\": [ \"00000000000000000000000000000000\", \"session\", \"login\", { \"username\": \"root\", \"password\": \"admin01\"  } ] }"

Comment: Transport security already done, but it's not helping

Comment: Separated error and code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
                    if(response.result.isFailure){
                        print("no data!");

                    }else{
                      print("received data!");

// make sure we got some JSON since that's what we expect
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
                print("didn't get todo object as JSON from API")
                print("Error: \(response.result.error)")
                return
            }

            print(json)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I got: received data!

Comment: That means this is working..just put your code there now

Comment: but then I try print result json, I get same error code = "-32700";
        message = "Parse error";
    };
    id = "<null>";
    jsonrpc = "2.0";

Comment: @GediminasUrbonas Then you ned to check with your JSON format properly. Parse error indicates that there is something wrong while parsing your JSON.

Comment: I am going to add at my question request which I make with terminal and JSon which I should get, could you help me with that?